# How to create Magento Webservices for mobile application?

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile, web-services, application

We have 1 magento e-commerce website and we need to create mobile application (android) for that.
can you please tell me how can we create web services for that website. please give me setps and any code documentation for that.

Comment: Use Magento API http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html